# SQL query: return all rows in A that are not in B and an additional criterion

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2008.  My goal is find all rows in table A that are not in table B.  I also want to find all rows in table A where two certain conditions in table B are met.  My basic query for the first part is:

```
SELECT
table_A.some_col
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
ON table_A.A_key = table_B.B_key
WHERE
table_B.B_key IS NULL
```

To get the second part, my best guess is:

```
SELECT
table_A.some_col
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
ON table_A.A_key = table_B.B_key
WHERE
table_B.B_key IS NULL
OR
table_B.another_col = 'some_value'
OR
table_B.yet_another_col = 'some_other_value'
```

However, this is giving me far more rows returned than expected.  Do I need to fix this by using a UNION instead?

Comment: You've already effectively combined them in your second query.  It sounds to me like you want two queries, on checking for null, one checking for the two table_b columns, and then, as you said, unioning them together.

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
table_A.some_col
FROM table_A

where not exists
(  select * from table_B
where /* relationship */ table_A.A_key = table_B.B_key and  /* any conditions you want */ table_B.B_key IS NULL and table_B.ColX = 'abc' )
```

OR

```
SELECT
table_A.some_col
FROM table_A

where not exists
(  select * from table_B
where /* relationship */ table_A.A_key = table_B.B_key )

UNION ALL

    SELECT
table_A.some_col
FROM table_A

where exists
(  select * from table_B
where table_B.B_key IS NULL and table_B.ColX = 'abc' )
```

Post some DDL, some sample INSERTS and expected results if you want more defined than that.

Comment: My tables are very large.  Won't WHERE NOT EXISTS really slow it down?

Comment: If the table is properly indexed...it will work....the only way to know for sure is to test it and follow normal indexing techniques